# Как пишется число Пи?

Tags: выбор-слов

С большой буквы? С маленькой? в кавычках или без?

Answer (score 1):

В орфографическом словаре на [Грамоте.ру](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BF%D0%B8&all=x) со строчной и без кавычек — ***пи***.

В Нацкорпусе встречается как в кавычках, так и без. Но всегда со строчной.

Answer (score 1):

Пишут кто как хочет, смотря кто, где и зачем. Это общепринятый термин, так что лучше, конечно, и написание применять общеизвестное - греческой буквой.

Вот употребление математиками: Жуков А. В. О числе Пи. М.: МЦНМО, 2002.

↑ Кымпан Ф., История числа Пи, М., Наука, 1971. с. 81.

Видимо, здесь употреблено как символ.

В обычных школьных работах пишут в основном со строчной и без кавычек, но кто-то и с большой - видимо, как учитель научил.